# How to write F'P vector in Latex?

Tags: vector

I've been trying to Type the following for a long time:

[image]

or the vector F'P. But the symbol ' is appearing as appearing as an apostrophe symbol and the Vector arrow is quite small.  I wrote the following code to display F'P vector:

```
$\vec{\textbf{F}\prime\textbf{P}}$
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}

$\overline{\bm{F'\!P}}$
$\bm{\overline{F'\!P}}$
$\overrightarrow{\bm{F'\!P}}$
$\bm{\overrightarrow{F'\!P}}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Actually, I would like to have an arrow instead of a bar above F'P. The journal from which I copied this image, must have made a typo. Please suggest a vector symbol that would span over all the alphabets.

Comment: @ShreyAryan Just use `\overrightarrow` instead of `\overline`

Comment: @ShreyAryan updated answer with variants

Comment: @Srey Aryan: Comment aside, you should give a try to the arrows of the `esvec` package. Their arrow tips (8 different shapes) do not touch capital letters.